# How to see exactly what is linked into my program?

Tags: linux, build, linker

Is it possible to use a command line utility in Linux to determine what is linked into my executable?

A way to prove I am not linking, statically or dynamically, to another piece of specific code.

Comment: Have you looked at ldd? I think this is what you want, but not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Yes that is kind of what I am looking for, but it only does .so files/dynamic linking, right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124571/get-list-of-static-libraries-used-in-an-executable has a suggestion (use nm), but that's not super useful. 

If you want to really prove it you could try to compile/link/run in a 'clean' environment without the 'specific code' in question.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments - for dynamic linking, you have ldd.

But if you want to see the statically linked libraries, it gets difficult and depends on your setup:
if you own the source code the accepted answer:

- [Can I get a report of ALL the libraries linked when building my C++ executable (gcc)? (including statically linked)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925012/can-i-get-a-report-of-all-the-libraries-linked-when-building-my-c-executable)

is your friend.

If not, you will at least have to know which libraries are suspected to be statically linked at.

If you have a huge code base and need to provide legal evidence you can use a software like [black duck](https://www.blackducksoftware.com/) which checks even if a developer has copied source code with not matching licenses.